# how to display bottom 3 result in ascending order in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

i have a table listed as below

```
id | color
---|-----
1  | red
2  | pink
3  | blue
4  | violet
5  | yellow
```

and i have this query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM colors WHERE id='".$rowId."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3";
$result = $db->query($query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
    echo $row['id']."-";
    echo $row['color'];
}
```

which displays the result accordingly

```
5 - yellow
4 - violet
3 - blue
```

when i use `ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 3`
it displays the 3 results starting from the TOP

```
1  - red
2  - pink
3  - blue
```

**what i want to happen is to display the top 3 BOTTOM in ASC order**

```
3 - blue
4 - violet
5 - yellow
```

so if i updated the table and added a new row, it should show as

```
4 - violet
5 - yellow
6 - green
```

Answer (score 1):

Then use subquery like this:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM colors WHERE id=$rowId ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3) AS internal 
ORDER BY 
  id ASC
```